# Getting a substring in a for loop in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I'm trying to parse through some XML files in my folder and get a substring of the each file name. Here's what I got in my .bat file:

```
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
    echo %%f
    echo %%f:~3,-4%%
)
```

The first echo prints out the file name just fine. But the second echo is what I'm having trouble with. I'm getting outputs like, say, for NewABCDEFG.xml:

```
NewABCDEFG.xml
NewABCDEFG.xml:~3,-4%
```

When I should be getting:

```
NewABCDEFG.xml
ABCDEFG
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. If I run the substring command in command line by itself, it works fine. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following script:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*.xml) do (
set filename=%%f
echo !filename:~7,-4!
)
```

The set line was what I really needed to get this to work, to expand environment variables at execution time, per the help guide.

Comment: Do a little more reading of the help file for the `FOR` command.  It is super easy to remove the file extension of a file if you use the command modifiers.  It is the very last section of the help file.

Answer (score 0):

First change `%%f` to `%%I`, that will make it easier read.

```
for %%I in (*.xml) do echo %%I & echo %%~nI
```

No need for delayed expansion in this case. My preference however is to avoid having multi-command line blocks:

```
for %%I in (*.xml) do call :DoIt %%I
exit /b
:DoIt
echo %1
echo %~n1
exit /b 0
```

Also avoid the possible confusion between replacement variable and the modifiers, allowing you to use `%%a`..`%%z` or `%%A`..`%%Z` for instance.